# Saving running applications

Tags: java, save

I have a program where I need to save a running application to be able to go back to it later
I know that I can write/read from a text file to achieve this but the program is pretty prodigious so it's not really a good way to do it because I have 10+ classes and thousands of JTextFields, JComboBoxs, etc. Does anyone know of a way I can achieve this without writing/reading from text files?

An example of what I need to be able to do is this:

In Microsoft Excel you can load files (.exl) into it and be able to edit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Swing Application Framework](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingappfr/#sessionstate) provides a way to save session state when your application exits and restore the state when you restart. Session state is the graphical window configuration of your application. This state includes window size, internal frame locations, selected tabs, column widths, and other graphical properties.

Comment: Looking at what you posted, what i want to do is possible but i have run into a problem: The class that i need to save or whatever already extends a JFrame and from what you posted it looks like i have to extend the ApplicationContext class, do you have any ideas of what i should do to solve this problem?

Comment: Look at this example http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingappfr/#code18 You can use your extended JFrame in such code. From getMainFrame(); method you can return your extended JFrame.

Comment: I am using NetBeans and it says there is no ApplicationContext class and i also changed JFrame mainFrame = getMainFrame() to JFrame mainFrame = this; would that work?

Comment: In NetBeans better create new project. File->New Project->Java->Java Desktop Application. This is dedicated project type for Swing Application Framework. Look at this tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/68/java/gui-saf.html. Alternatively you can add its libraries to existing project: click on Libraries->Add Library->Swing Application Framework and click Add Library.

Comment: That worked out the problem with the ApplicationContext (thank you) but now it says there is no method getContext in the line ApplicationContext ctx = getContext();

Comment: This listing is not a complete solution, but usage sample. It demonstrates how to save application state. To get to know how to embed your code in Swing Application Framework please read whole article and look at tutorial. It is really very simple :)

Comment: @Michael: if you choose this solution you should mark it as accepted (tick at left, below vote count).

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is to save the data from your controls into a canonical form and then make that class serializable. You can then persist that data to a file. Here's [a link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) about serialization in Java.

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that you said you have *thousands* of form controls. So you probably don't want to do all of this in one class, but you probably want to maintain a hierarchy of classes and split out the data into separate classes. This will also help you separate your concerns. Hopefully you have POJOs or domain classes that represents your data. If that is the case, your task will be much easier. This is also why separating concerns is good :).

Comment: @Michael oh, it wasn't directed at you. Someone else downvoted me.

Answer (score 1):

How do you think Excel does this?  It stores the type and value of each cell, along with metadata describing the worksheet in its own proprietary binary format in a file.  If you have a custom application with complex internal state, you will have to design a storage format and serialize the state yourself.  You *may* be able to use Java Serialization, but not without some effort.

Answer (score 0):

To save the state of an application, i can think of two popular way:

1) save the state of the application in a Database
2) save the state of the application in a binary file or XML,json or any format you want.

Maybe giving more details about the app. would help.

is it a Web app, fat client app, client/server app...  !^

Solution may vary with the type of application.

Hope it help.